# How do I curve hair with curve modifier?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo_FxdSe_F8&t=616s , wich lets you edit the hair flat and then snap it to a curve with a curve modifier

but I can't get the hairstrand or anything to snap to the location of the curve as he does in the tutorial, I have to place it where the curve is wich kind of defeats the purpose of making edits on the side

if i place my object to the side of the character and use the curve modifier it flies way off where the curve is, even if I apply transformations and have the origins near the end of each object

Answer (score 0):

The guy who made the tutorial probably could have mentioned this, but it's no biggie either way.

Notice how between cuts, right where you timestamped, this button is lit up?

[image]

And then afterwards its dimmed?

Thats the *View Modifier in Viewport* button. Think of it like "Mute" but for modifiers.

EDIT:
If you want to be able to edit it with the curve in place then click this button, *View in Edit Mode*

[image]

Comment: Sorry what I mean is in the video he has the ability to edit the object when it is on the side of the head, and when he applies the curve modifier it snaps to the position of the curve, but when I apply the curve modifier it ends up far away from the curve and the only way to make it work is to move the object to the position of the curve. and that just makes it not very good to work with.  https://imgur.com/a/AzyhLRF     https://imgur.com/a/Il7Ekzc

Comment: I think I know the problem, I edited my answer a bit.

Comment: I solved it, he mentioned it in the video but I'd missed it, the origin point of the curve must be placed at the origin point of the object